# remove table row without reload page in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, tablerow

I know its repeated question, but i tried the solutions available and still not working.. i want to remove the row from view in angular without reloading page .. what is the problem in this code?

html: the body of table contains data from database:

```
<tbody id='t'>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in ItemsByPage[currentPage]">
                        <td>
                            <div  ng-model="tid"> {{item.id}} </div>                                
                        </td>
                        <td><div editable-text="item.name" onaftersave='inlineupdateName(item.id,item.name)' ng-model="tname" data-n='item.name'>{{item.name}}</div>

                        <td><div editable-text="item.phone" onaftersave='inlineupdatephone(item.id,item.phone)'  ng-model="tphone">{{item.phone}}</div>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

and html code for delete and update rows:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input  type="text" ng-model="delId" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter user id to delete th user">                        
                    <button ng-click="deleteuser()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete User</button> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input  type="text" ng-model="updateId" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter user id to update his phone"> 
                    <input  type="text" ng-model="updatePhone" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter user new phone">
                    <button ng-click="updateuser()" type="button" >Update User</button>
                </div>
```

delete and update functions:

```
$scope.deleteuser = function () {
                var id = $scope.delId;
                console.log(id);
                var data = {delId : $scope.delId};
                $http.post('delete.php', data )
                  .success(function(response) {
                    // splice not working
                    $scope.ItemsByPage.splice(id,1); 
                  });  

            };

            $scope.updateuser = function () {
                var data = {
                    updateId: $scope.updateId,
                    updatePhone: $scope.updatePhone
                };
                var phone = $scope.updatePhone;
                $http.post('update.php', data )
                  .success(function(response) {
                      //what to do here to update data without reloading??                          
                  });  

            };
```

Edit:  the module and service :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["xeditable"]);
        myApp.service('ListService', function () {                
            this.paged = function (valLists, pageSize) {
                retVal = [];                  
                for (var i = 0; i < valLists.length; i++) {
                    if (i % pageSize === 0) {
                        retVal[Math.floor(i / pageSize)] = [valLists[i]];
                    } else {
                        retVal[Math.floor(i / pageSize)].push(valLists[i]);
                    }
                }
                return retVal;
            };
        });
var TableCtrl = myApp.controller('TableCtrl', function ($scope, ListService,$http) {
            $scope.pageSize = 3;               
            $http.post('select.php')
                .success(function(response) {
                    //alert(response);
                    $scope.allItems = response;
                    $scope.resetAll();
                    $scope.pagination();
                });

            $scope.resetAll = function () {
                $scope.List = $scope.allItems;
                $scope.newId = '';
                $scope.newName = '';
                $scope.newPhone = '';
                $scope.currentPage = 0;
            };
           $scope.pagination = function () {
                $scope.ItemsByPage = ListService.paged($scope.List, $scope.pageSize);

            };
});
$scope.setPage = function () {
                $scope.currentPage = this.n;
            };

            $scope.firstPage = function () {
                $scope.currentPage = 0;
            };

            $scope.lastPage = function () {
                $scope.currentPage = $scope.ItemsByPage.length - 1;
            };
```

Comment: can you provide the data design of `ItemsByPage` ? and what's in currentPage ? is it defined in scope or something else ?

Comment: I guess. you are using xeditable table, Is it?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi i did .. take a look

Comment: @SatyamKoyani yes i use x-editable

Comment: Are you getting any error in splice. You said splice is not working?

Comment: no there are no errors , it just doesnt remove the row from table in view

Comment: Try this $scope.ItemsByPage[$scope.currentPage].splice(id,1);

Comment: @SatyamKoyani it fires error :  $scope.ItemsByPage[$scope.currentPage].splice(id,1); is undefined